# Keep getting seg fault after input in C program

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I am running into a error in my C program where it seg faults after inputting but I'm not sure where the error is. The program is suppose to dynamically allocate memory for a movie list and be able to add and search to the list. I'm not sure whats wrong with, I think it has something to do with my buffer.

The program accepts a command line argument for the movies.txt file contents:

5
Mission Impossible
Action
4
2008
Up
Action
3
2012

The user inputs the movie name to search or to display movies by name or rating

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// limit definition
#define LIMIT 100

//movie structure
struct movie
{
char name[100];
char type[30];
int rating;
int releaseDate;
};

//reads file 
void readFile(FILE *fp,struct movie* movieList[],int *noOfReviews)
{
    char buffer[100];
    int counter = 0;
    struct movie* newNode;
    fgets(buffer,LIMIT,fp);
    *noOfReviews = atoi(buffer); // number of reviews in buffer
    printf("%d",*noOfReviews); //prints reviews
    while((fgets(buffer,LIMIT,fp)!=NULL) || (*noOfReviews > 0)) //if null or reviews greater than zero
    {
        if(counter % 4 == 0)
        {
        struct movie* tmpNode = (struct movie*)malloc(sizeof(struct movie)); //allocates memory
        movieList[counter] = tmpNode;
        newNode = tmpNode;
        *noOfReviews--; // --#ofreviews
        }
        //copys struc into buffer
    switch(counter % 4 )
        {

        case 0:
        strcpy(newNode->name,buffer);
        break;
        case 1:
        strcpy(newNode->type,buffer);
        break;
        case 2:
        newNode->rating = atoi(buffer);
        break;
        case 3:
        newNode->releaseDate = atoi(buffer);
        break;
        default:
        printf("Exception\n");
        break;
    }
    counter++;
    }
}
//searches list
int searchList(struct movie* movielist[],char movieName[],int noOfMovies)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(noOfMovies--)
    {
    if(strcmp(movielist[counter]->name,movieName) == 0) // if string compares to name
    {
        return counter;
    }
    counter++;
    }
    return -1;
}
//compares strings of name
int nameStrCmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (strcmp(((struct movie*)a)->name,((struct movie*)b)->name));
}
// compares rating strings
int ratingStrCmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return (((struct movie*)a)->rating - ((struct movie*)b)->rating);
}
//displays the structure
void display(struct movie* movieList[],int n)
{
int i;
struct movie* searchRslt;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
searchRslt = movieList[i];// search result index of movies list
//prints struct information
printf("name:%s\n type:%s\n rating:%d\n releaseDate:%d\n",searchRslt->name,searchRslt->type,searchRslt->rating,searchRslt->releaseDate);

}
}
//main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[100];
int noOfReviews;
struct movie* movieList[1000];
struct movie *searchRslt;
char mName[100];
if(argc <= 1)
{
    printf("invalid");
    return 0;
}
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(!fp){ 
    printf("cant open file\n"); 
}
readFile(fp,movieList,&noOfReviews);
while(1)
{
//case selection menu
int input;
printf("Enter 1 to search for a movie.\n");
printf("Enter 2 to display the list of movies by name.\n");
printf("Enter 3 to display the list of movies by rating.\n");
scanf("%d",&input);
switch(input)
{
    case 1:
    printf("Enter movie name to search:");
    scanf("%s",mName);
    int index = searchList(movieList,mName,noOfReviews);
    if(index < 0)
        printf("Not found!!\n"); // if movie not found 
    else // gets movies
    {
    searchRslt = movieList[index];
    printf("name:%s\n type:%s\n rating:%d\n releaseDate:%d\n",searchRslt->name,searchRslt->type,searchRslt->rating,searchRslt->releaseDate);
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    qsort(movieList,noOfReviews,sizeof(struct movie),nameStrCmp);
    display(movieList,noOfReviews);
    break;
    case 3:
    qsort(movieList,noOfReviews,sizeof(struct movie),ratingStrCmp);
    display(movieList,noOfReviews);
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program through a debugger such as GDB to see where the segmentation fault is occurring?

Comment: I tried installing GDB debugger on my mac laptop since I am not on my computer that I have it on(linux) but I can't seem to properly install it, it just keeps updating homebrew or just gives me error and I've even followed tutorials that go as far as certifying my keychain and stuff, hence I asked here.

Comment: What are the arguments for the call of your program?  What is the content of the files of the parameters?  What are the user inputs?

Comment: @HeLLo I edited the question

Comment: In `readFile()` make some printfs in your switch statement.  You will be surprised: `case 0: strcpy(newNode->name, buffer); printf("buffer: '%s'\n", buffer); printf("name: '%s'\n", newNode->name); break;`

Comment: On Mac you can use `lldb` to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflows in various places may occur in various places in your code. Your code is full of arrays with hardcoded sizes and it is often unclear whether the size limitation is adhered to by all code accessing these arrays. Try hard to avoid arrays with hardcoded sizes and allocate these dynamically instead. And if you really want to use hardcoded array sizes in some places use a "size" constant of some kind and try to ensure you adhere to it by have a neat structure in the code like a function which writes to "name" which never will exceed names size, etc.

It is easy to crash your program when the input lines for "type" are longer than 29 characters including the line termination. This is because you copy the read line `buffer` (may contain up to 99 chars) into `newNode->type` (may contain up to 29 chars) using `strcpy` which may write past the end of the buffer (buffer overflow).

Another way to crash you program is to pass it more than 1000 movie records.